# JSTL gt compare is not working

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm not sure why this snip is not working, 
trying to set the length value then check if it's greater than 1 to display delete link.

```
<c:set var="test" value="${fn:length(planInfoList)}"/>
    ${test} <!-- here the vale is 2 -->

    <c:if test="${test gt 1}  " >
        <a  href="deletePlanInfo.do?planInfoId=${planInfo.planInfoId }">
<img src="remove.png" />Delete</a>

</c:if>
```

the value of the set is 2, but still not displaying the  link, what Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing spaces in `test` attribute:

```
<c:if test="${test gt 1}  " ></c:if>
                        ^
                   remove here
```

Comment: I can't believe I've done something like this mistake! Thanks a lot :)